# "Ride the Bus" optimal game strategy

Tags: probability, game-theory, card-games

Ride the bus is a drinking game that involves making a set of choices correctly in a row to win and stop playing. The player who is riding the bus must complete **all four in a row**. A random card is drawn each time **without replacement**. Getting a question wrong means taking a drink and starting back at question one. In order here are the four questions.

1. Red or black
2. Higher or lower
3. Inside or outside
4. Suit

[Ride the bus visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA8xK.png)

Any failure at any stage requires that player to start BACK at question one

Optionally, one can call "post" this means if the next card is the same card (just number on the card not suit or color) they win and the game is over.

**Are you more likely to win by playing the questions normally or is it better to call "post" every time?**

Comment: Is there an issue with this post?

Comment: Does "without replacement" mean that an unlucky player can exhaust the deck? Are the cards replaced and shuffled in that eventuality? Or is the scope only the round, and the cards are replaced whenever the game resets to step 1?

Comment: To clarify, yes if the player is very unlucky they may exhaust the deck. In that event the cards are all shuffled and the game continues in the same spot. The reason I said "without replacement" was to mention the cards are not put back in and shuffled after each round only when the cards have run out. Thank you!